# Android Google Maps don't work

Tags: google-play-services

I was  trying  make simple app with Google Maps. But when I run app in emulator, maps don't showing up, only showing this text: "[name of app] won't run unless you update Google Play services". I  installed emulator Nexus 5 with Nougat 7.1 (with Google API). I didn't find solution on google. Can I run Google Maps application on emulator or I must test on real devices?

UPDATE: In build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.malikbisic.mapsdemo"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can run it using the emulator, but make sure your android emulator is with an [AVD](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Check this [thread](http://hmkcode.com/run-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator/) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUsBOZ7-qBE) to know how to setup and use the android emulator to Run Google Maps.